# How to determine Absolute Convergence and Conditional Convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

In this hw problem it is asking to determine the absolute convergence values and place them in interval notation same as for conditional convergence.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
My question is where would I go from this? (Hints would be preferred as I still need to learn how to approach these problems.)

Comment: [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

Comment: @EvanAad Do you think you could explain the ratio test a bit? We have not gone over that particular test in class yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't learned ratio test yet, then the only thing you have is geometric series.  We need two facts:  1.  a geometric series converges if the common ratio is between $-1$ and $1$ (open interval.)  2.  The harmonic series diverges and the alternating harmonic series converges.  Then we do cases:

If $\mid x \mid >1$ then the absolute version of your series is greater than $\sum 1/n$ and so diverges.

If $0\leq x <1$, then your series is less than $\sum x^n$ which is geometric and converges (absolutely.)

If $x=1$ then the series diverges (harmonic.)

If $x=-1$ then the series converges conditionally (alternating harmonic.)

Answer (score 0):

Absolute convergence: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\frac{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{x^n}{n}}|=|x|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}<1\,$ => $\,|x|<1$